# Make Label + Input move to next line together if input overflows

Tags: html, css

I have a menubar that looks like this

## #label1 #input1 #label2 #input2 #label3 #input3

Now let's say that I run out of space on my window, I need them to move to the next line together so I get this:

## #label1 #input1 #label2 #input2

## #label3 #input3

instead of

## #label1 #input1 #label2 #input2 #label3

## #input3

I was able to get every label input pair to move together by writing this

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label...><input...></span>
```

The problem though is that the label3 and input3 pair won't wrap to the next line until label3 is completely cut off by the browser window (until that happens I get a scroll bar). I want it so that if input3 gets slightly cut off, label3 and input3 move onto the next line immediately.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or codepen ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddiqui has the right idea. You can use the `<wbr>` tag to indicate where you want the line breaks to appear. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VNenK/

More info on wbr: http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html